# Angular - Recompile/White screen on new tab opening

Tags: angular

We have an Angular (5) app. It takes a couple of seconds to compile when you first login (we are ok with this). In certain circumstances we open a new tab. This uses a standard link with target set to _blank. When the 2nd tab loads, we get the same "pause"/white screen whilst the compilation happens.

Is there any way to take advantage of the fact the browser has done the compilation and just use this again, or are we stuck until we can make some changes to get AOT working

Comment: Your highest priority should be to make AOT working, and no, there is no way of taking advantage of already done compilation. JIT is only made for development purposes to make developing/rebuild time faster. Especially with Ivy being in the opt-in phase, you should really reconsider upgrading your project

Comment: @PierreDuc. Thanks, i was hoping there was a magic switch. We do some serverside rendering that stops us doing AOT right now. Once that is switched, then we would be able to move on!

Comment: Depending on what you are rendering, you could make the server side rendering done in the build phase, but it will probably require you to 'eject' the project. Either way, the optimal situation would be to have static templates and have these filled using API/firebase